# Show git diff of the current line in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, git-diff

Is there a shortcut to show the git diff of the current line like it's done with the mouse in the GIF?[image]

I've tried to find this action in the key bindings, but it seems like it's not even an action. I've also tried to detect the appearing "window", but no luck. I've also tried to use GitLens, but it also doesn't allow you to set a shortcut to toggle hover of the current line.

Comment: Do you mean a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a hint on the right-hand side of the dialog that appears...

- Show Next Change (<kbd>⌥F3</kbd>)
- Show Previous Change (<kbd>⬆⌥F3</kbd>)

Pressing the first one when on a changed section will display the dialog for that section.

That's on macOS anyway. The Linux / Windows equivalents probably use <kbd>ALT+F3</kbd>.

From the default key mappings preferences

| Command | Keybinding | When | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Show Next Change | <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> | `editorTextFocus && !textCompareEditorActive` | System |
| Show Previous Change | <kbd>⬆</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> | `editorTextFocus && !textCompareEditorActive` | System |

Comment: Thank you! Alt+F3 does work on my Fedora! That was fast.